# How to access a part of URL address (not full URL) in Django template

Tags: python, django

How do I get '12' which is the `id` of teacher model in this path from Django template?

> http://localhost:8000/editTeacher/12/

I searched a bit and I know how to get the entire url, but don't know how do I get a part of it.

I also tried using `request.get('id')` but it didn't work!

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('addTeacher/', addTeacherView, name='add-teacher'),
    path('listTeacher/', listTeacherView, name='list-teacher'),
    path('teacherIndex/<int:my_id>/', teacherIndexView, name='teacher-index'),
    path('deleteTeacher/<int:my_id>/',
         deleteTeacherView, name='delete-teacher-view'),
    path('editTeacher/<int:my_id>/', editTeacherView, name='edit-teacher'),
    path('', homeView, name='home')
]
```

My views.py:

```
def editTeacherView(request, my_id):
    my_instance = Teacher.objects.get(id=my_id)
    teacher = TeacherForm(request.POST or None, instance=my_instance)
    if teacher.is_valid():
        teacher.save()
        return redirect('../../listTeacher/')
    context = {
        'editTeacher': teacher
    }
    return render(request, 'teacher/editTeacher.html/', context)
```

And this one below is the view I will be using in order to grab the id of the teacher from url and delete it from database

```
def deleteTeacherView(request, my_id):
    try:
        teacher = Teacher.objects.get(id=my_id)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            teacher.delete()
            return redirect('../../listTeacher/')
    except Teacher.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    context = {
        'teacherId': teacher
    }
    return render(request, 'teacher/deleteTeacher.html', context)
```

this is editTeacher.html page:

```
<form method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ editTeacher.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
    <a href="../../deleteTeacher/{{ #grab_id }}/">Delete</a>

</form>
```

Comment: That comes with correctly defining your paths. Show us your urls.py and your view.

Comment: A couple of tips: your code would be clearer if you use `teacher = Teacher.objects.get(id=my_id)` in both views, then use `form = TeacherForm(request.POST or None, instance=teacher)` in the edit view. For function based views in Django, the usual names would be `edit_teacher_view` and `delete_teacher_view`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of logic belongs in the view, not the template. You can pass the `my_id` to the template context in your view, for example:

```
def editTeacherView(request, my_id):
    context = {
        ...
        my_id: my_id,
    }
    return render(request, "edit_teacher.html", context}
```

Then in your template you can do `{{ my_id }}`

```
<a href="../../deleteTeacher/{{ my_id }}/">Delete</a>
```

Note that it's a bad idea to hardcode URLs like this. You can use the `{% url %}` tag instead:

```
<a href="{% url 'delete-teacher-view' my_id %}>
```

If you use a namespace (e.g. app_name = 'teachers'`), then you'll need to include this in the tag:

```
<a href="{% url 'teachers:delete-teacher-view' my_id %}>
```

Similarly, in your views you can use the URL name when you redirect instead of hardcoding the URL:

```
return redirect('list-teacher')
```

Comment: I thank you for taking time and answering it. I read your comment and answer both. I am kind of confused how to do that. I tried it and get an error, probably because I couldn't get the explanation well, my fault. if you don't mind can you please edit my codes so I understand how is your approach. I want to grab the id and delete that teacher!

Comment: You have `{{ #grab_id }}` in your latest update -- I've showed you that you should use `{{ my_id }}` once you've added `my_id` to the `context` dictionary in `editTeacherView`. If you still can't get it working, please update your question with the updated view and template, and any error message you get.

Comment: Thank you so much bro, God bless you